# Raspbian Stretch with MariaDB

Tags: pi-zero, mysql

For the last 6 hours I have been trying to install MariaDB on my Raspberry Pi Zero.
I am using the latest Raspbian Stretch.
The problem is that the configuration menu for MariaDB doesn't show up during installation (which I believe it should) and it doesn't ask me to set the root password. After installation I cannot login to the MariaDB server with `mysql` using any credentials, but if I run `mysql` with root priviliges (`sudo mysql`) it lets me in without any form of authentication.
I tried running `mysql_secure_installation` after install, but it didn't help.
By the way I am trying to install phpMyAdmin.

EDIT: I ended up using Raspbian Jessie, and the configuration dialog popped up as it should, and I could configure the password, and everything worked perfectly fine.

I am (and probably others too) still looking for a solution to this though. I also noticed that on Stretch the `debian-sys-maint` user wasn't created either, and `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` was containing a bad login (user root with no pass).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am running Apache, PHP, MyAdmin and MariaDB on a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch Lite using this sequence, and it works perfectly.

1. Update

   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
2. install mariadb server and client

   sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
3. install apache and php

   sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
4. install phpmyadmin

   sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
5. fix the msqli missing extension

   sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
6. setup password and secure setup

   sudo mysql_secure_installation

Finished, reboot.

Now if you still get a login/password error then you need to disable 
Mysql from trying to authenticate root using plugin, and not password.

```
sudo mysql -u root

[mysql] use mysql;
[mysql] update user set plugin='' where User='root';
[mysql] flush privileges;
[mysql] \q
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. The last info block about the plugin actually solved my problem I had with the login without sudo.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't have time to test this whole thing earlier. The project is now back on table. With your help I was able to get everything working. I'm using PHP 7.0. This is how I did it:
`sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client` then set plugin via sudo (last info block), `sudo apt-get install apache2`, `sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0`, `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`, `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, `sudo mysql_secure_installation`
I did this on the latest Raspbian Lite (2017-11-29)

Answer (score 0):

I just got my Raspberry Pi 3 and I've had problems running phpMyAdmin. I've started from scratch a couple of times, and this time I got it finally running. I did the usual steps as suggested by Dr. Rabbit above.

Then, I edited Apache 2's configuration file:
**sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

And included a line:
**/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf**

And finally reloaded the web server:
**sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload**

I'm a complete Linux noob, and this was absolute trial and error, but it seems to be working. Strangely.. I got the idea for this from Ubuntu guides (e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin )

Comment: It's not strange at all.  While GNU/Linux (a more formal label) distributions are independent, they are 99% built from the same basic pieces, and most of the differences are fairly trivial.  So generally speaking the documentation produced by one distro is often 100% applicable to another.  In addition, there are two main streams, Debian derived distros, and Fedora derived distros.  Raspbian and Ubuntu are the former. I find some of the [best linux user documentation is produced by Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Table_of_contents), although I've almost never used the distro itself.